# Android use case and repository unit testing

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

I am having issues unit testing my use case. Here is the use case code-

```
    interface MyUseCase {
        fun performCustomAction(action: MyAction): LiveData<Result>
    }

    class MyUseCaseImpl(private val dataRepository: DataRepository) : MyUseCase {

       override fun performCustomAction(action: MyAction) = liveData {
          emit(Result.DataFetchInProgress)
          emit(dataRepository.performDataOperation(action))
       }
    }
```

Here is the corresponding unit test -

```
class MyUseCaseImplTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    private lateinit var myUseCase: MyUseCase

    @Mock
    private lateinit var dataRepository: DataRepository

    @Mock
    private lateinit var liveData: LiveData<Result>

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
        myUseCase = spy(MyUseCaseImpl(dataRepository))
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    fun myUseCase_loginUser_expectedUserLoggedIn() {
        val result: LiveData<Result> = myUseCase.performCustomAction(
            MyAction.LoginUser(
                "userName", "password"
            )
        )

        Assert.assertEquals(result, liveData)
    }
}
```

I get this error when I run this unit test -

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :androidx.lifecycle.CoroutineLiveData@4c012563
Actual   :liveData
```

What mistake am i doing here?

Also could you please suggest me what else I can test in my use case

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. Basically I needed to add a `Mockito.when(...).thenReturn(livedata)`.
Here is the code below -

```
@Test
fun myUseCase_loginUser_expectedUserLoggedIn() {
    `when`(
        myUseCase.performCustomAction(
          MyAction.LoginUser(
            "userName", "password"
          )
        )
    ).thenReturn(liveData)

    val result = myUseCase.performCustomAction(
        MyAction.LoginUser(
            "userName", "password"
        )
    )

    Assert.assertThat(result, `is`(liveData))
}
```